# Is it possible to use a css class in another css class?

Tags: css

What I'm trying to do is refer a css class in another css class:

```
.customClass1{
     //some styles
}

.customClass2{
     //some styles
}

.customClass3{
     use customClass1;
     use customClass2;
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why don't add those two class to the element ? ..... or in the CSS `.customClass1, .customClass3 {`

Comment: Not using vanilla CSS. You can use mixins with LESS.js however.

Comment: In purse CSS, no. But something like Sass's [`@extend`](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-7) will do what you want.

Comment: basically why would you want to?  whichever attribute you're using the css class, you combine the classes.   <a href="#" class="customClass1 customClass2 customClass3">your styled link</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a CSS pre-processor like LESS, then you can use Mixins [LESS Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature)